# facebook, google plus and twitter implementation on my site

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-chrome, twitter, google-plus

Here  is the code i am using for the facebook, google plus and twitter implementation on my site. FB, Google Plus and Twitter are showing up in IE, but FB doesnt show up in browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc. I think this is because of the iframe tag. I observed that iframe is missing in other browsers. When I include iframe for FB in firebug manually, I can see FB also. Can someone suggest me a solution? Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript">

    var strFacebookImple = "<%=strFaceBookImpl %>";
    if (strFacebookImple == "true") {
    (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');

        (function() {
            var scrGooglePlus = document.createElement('script');
            scrGooglePlus.type = 'text/javascript';
            scrGooglePlus.async = true;
            scrGooglePlus.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var scrWriter = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            scrWriter.parentNode.insertBefore(scrGooglePlus, scrWriter);
        })();

        (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        (function() {
            var scrTwitter = document.createElement('script');
            scrTwitter.type = 'text/javascript';
            scrTwitter.async = true;
            scrTwitter.src = document.location.protocol + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            var scrWriter = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            scrWriter.parentNode.insertBefore(scrTwitter, scrWriter);
        })(); }
```

```
       <div class="CB PADL30">

                      <% if (FU.NullToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fBImpl"], "false") == "true")
                           { %>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="<%=strDomainSitename %>/Details.aspx?<%=strContentId %>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<%=strDomainSitename %>/Details.aspx?<%=strContentId %>" data-text="Mve" data-via="iouview" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>

                       <g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>
                        <%} %>

                     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try and reinvent the wheel. There's alot of things that can go wrong and/or conflict when trying to adding social media plugins to a site.

I use addthis on all my sites. You can grab and customize the code without registering, but registering an account gives you access to some pretty handy analytics. https://www.addthis.com